# get list of files with titles in folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api

So I'm getting files via the Google Drive API on the like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{...}/children?q={...}
```

But the JSON returned doesn't seem to include the title of files. Instead it's more like

```
{
    ...
    "items": [[{u'kind': u'drive#childReference', u'childLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/...', u'id': u'...', u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/.../children/...'}, ...]
}
```

Are applications forced to make a `get` on each of items to get the titles? That seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the request you are using is intended to just list children of a folder with limited information.
Maybe it will be useful for you to use the [files list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request with a restrictive query like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='0B7Gsb83y7LCsMHUweWFRUTlBeEU'+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

this way you will get a lot more of information about each node, you can limit the information you receive using the *fields* parameter, something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='0B7Gsb83y7LCsMHUweWFRUTlBeEU'+in+parents&fields=items%2Fdescription&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

you can build the *fields* parameters and know what options you have by using the "Fields editor" that is provided in the [help page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list), just search there for "Use fields editor"

Hope this helps, regards